# Read sqlite file in sdcard and display results in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite file in sdcard. I want to read this file without importing it into assets folder. I just want to read table and display values. No need to upgrade or insert values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply open the database with the following function. The further processing is like any other SQLite-DB.

```
private SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(final Context context) {
  final File databaseFile = new File("<path-to-your-db-file>")
  return SQLiteDatabase
        .openDatabase(databaseFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}
```

Please notice to grant your app the specific permissions to access the external storage.

Comment: Thank you......one more thing, path to db file is different for different devices even if i keep it in external memory card, do i have any solution for this one?